# iOS - Auto and manual Map routing with user motion and area calculation

Tags: ios, dictionary, routes, area

I am working on an iOS app whose functionality is to show google map with user current location. I successfully shown user location on map, now I need to draw a route as user moves from current location to another and then to next. Finally at the end on a button click I have to connect very fist location to last location. At the end I need to calculate the drown area in acres.

So I summarize my questions as follows :

1. How to draw user movement on map?
2. How to direct connect first and last location on a button click?
3. How to calculate user moved area?
4. If I want to draw route from last point to current point on manual click, how to do that?

Please provide any suitable code as well. I would appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Hi Lalit are you find the solution this question ?